# Maintaining multiple socket connections chat app

Tags: android

I am building an IRC client, which is a chat application based on the IRC protocol. In my app, I need to create a socket and make a connection to the server (ie: freenode.net) In this server there are multiple channels, and I have a list view of those channels. When I click on a channel item, I would like to make a connection to that channel by calling a new ConnectTask() and creating a new activity then start chatting. However, when I go back to the list view and click on the channel again, I want to resume to the chat stuff that I had before on ConnectTask(), also, I would like to connect to other channels as well and maintaining the status when I temporary "left" the channels. How would I achieve this? Should I open a new activity for each channel? or fragment? Should I use threads or some thing? Thank you very much!

**Connection.java**

```
public void start() throws IOException {
    running = true;

    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter
                        (socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                (socket.getInputStream()));

        send("NICK " + nick);
        send("USER " + username + " 0 * :" + realname);
        send("JOIN " + channel);

        while (running) {
            String message = in.readLine();
            if (message != null)
                listener.rcv(message);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

**ConnectTask() in SingleChannelActivity.**

```
private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Connection> {

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(String... params) {
        connection = new Connection(params[0],
                Integer.parseInt(params[1]),
                params[2],
                params[3]
                ,
                new Connection.MessageCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void rcv(String message) {
                        publishProgress(message);
                    }
                });

        try {
            connection.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        parseSrv(values[0]);
    }
}
```

**I call it when the activity started by the channel item is opened**

```
 new ConnectTask().execute("irc.freenode.net", "6667", nick, channel);
```

[image: Channel List View]

[image]

Comment: `However, when I go back to the list view and click on the channel again, I want to resume to the chat stuff that I had before... ` It is unclear what you consider to be 'chat stuff before'.

Comment: I mean I want to see the conversation before I left and not having to connect again to the channel. Basically I want to have multiple channels running at the same time :( Thanks

Comment: If you cannot ask the server to give you the conversations from a certain date-time then you have to save and retrieve them yourself. It's only a bit of text so saving and retrieving is easy.

Comment: I underatand, thanks for your help :)